# VBA to hyperlink addresses from one column to anchors in the next column

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns (E,F) where E has 2500 URLs for Articles and F has the Titles of those articles. As part of a larger macro I need to **hyperlink the titles in column F to the correlated URLs in column E**. If I wasn't doing this via VBA I'd use the hyperlink function.

The current attempt I made is below. It's not executing the command past the first hyperlink. Any suggestions?

```
i = 1
Do While i < 2500
    Cells(6, i).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(6, i), Address:=Cells(5, i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing rows and columns:

```
i = 1
Do While i < 2500
    Cells(i, 6).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(i, 6), Address:=Cells(i, 5)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

---

Note:  If you find it more readable, you can use column **letters** instead of column **numbers** as a parameter in the `Cells` property, e.g.

```
    Cells(i, "F").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Cells(i, "F"), Address:=Cells(i, "E")
```

I find it useful to use numbers when looping across columns, and use letters when I am referring to a specific, known, column.

Answer (score 0):

Even with rows and columns interpolated your code should run. I suspect that VBA objects to a blank cell (not its value, but the range) being assigned to the `Address` property. Heeding @YowE3K's good advice about addressing columns, I arrive at the code below.

```
Dim Hype As String
Dim R As Long                   ' row number

' Column E (5) = URLs
' Column F (6) = Product titles

With Worksheets("Sheet1")       ' specify your sheet
    For R = 1 To 2500
        Hype = .Cells(R, "E").value
        If Len(Hype) = 0 Then Exit For
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(R, "F"), _
                        Address:=Hype, _
                        TextToDisplay:=.Cells(R, "F").value
    Next R
End With
```

This code tries to deal with an apparent flaw in your logic. A hyperlink will display a name and act on a URL. Your sheet has the name in one column and the URL in another. So, where is the Hyperlink? My above code replaces the name in column F with the hyperlink. The cell will still display the same name, but the URL column will become obsolete.